# Submit html table as csv in POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv

I have an editable HTML table, and I'd like to submit the entire table to a PHP page as a single csv variable. The PHP page will then parse the csv and do its thing in the background. I don't want to use a single input per table cell because some of my tables are large and I will quickly run into truncation from POSTing more than 1000 variables. But a csv of the table is not too big and easy for me to parse on the backend.

So I'm looking for a package or method that will take a table like this

```
<table id="thetable">
    <tr>
        <td>cellA</td>
        <td>cellB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cellC</td>
        <td>cellD</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and submit it through POST as a variable, where the resulting variable on the server side would be something like

```
cellA,cellB\n
cellC,cellD
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mu5g1a7x/2/).

The implementation is basically these `map` functions on the cols and rows. You can use that `exportTableToCSV` function to get the desired string and just remove the download part.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to look through the `<tr>` of the table, then inside that loop, loop through the `<td>` values.  If you are just grabbing the value inside you can use the `.html()`

I haven't tested this, so it may need to be altered slightly.

So let's say you give your table an id of data-table

```
var data = [];

$('#data-table tr').each(function() {
  $('td', $(this)).each(function() {
     data.push($(this).html());
  });
});
```

Then join your array with a comma separator.